# How to access .env variables from "main.js" in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables

Trying to register my `env` variable `BASE_URL` with `Axios` in my `main.js`:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.BASE_URL
```

In my `.env` file, I have:

```
BASE_URL = https://www.my-site.com/wp/wp-json
```

But I'm getting "process is not defined" error. Is there a simple way to access `env` variables from `main.js`?

Comment: the dotenv package is one good option.

Comment: This totally depends on project setup, which is unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Env variable must start with "VITE_".

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using SSR, components will be rendered in browsers but not Node.js. That's why `process` is `undefined`.

With Vite: Use [`import.meta.env`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-variables)

With Webpack: [It is enabled by default](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code)

Comment: Using Vite. Already tried `import.meta.env.BASE_URL` before coming here to ask the question and it doesn't work (returns `/` instead of the correct value of `BASE_URL`)